# How to send audio blob from javascript to java spring server?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, webrtc

I'm recording some audio data in my javascript client using `RecordRTC`. I want to send this audio data to my Spring `RestController` via `WebSockets`.

After recording I have a blob object in my javascript client: `Blob {size: 65859, type: "audio/webm"}`

I tried to convert this blob to an ArrayBuffer object using `FileReader` which looks like this `ArrayBuffer {} byteLength: 65859`

My javascript code where I send the ArrayBuffer looks like this:

```
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener( 'loadend', () => {
        console.log( 'readerResult', reader.result );
        this.stompClient.send( "/app/hello", {}, reader.result );
    } );

    this.recorder.stopRecording(() => {
        const blob = this.recorder.getBlob();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer( blob );
        console.log( "blob", blob );
    } );
```

My WebSocket endpoint in my Spring Boot application looks like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
public void stream(byte[] input) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("incoming message ...");
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(input.length);
}
```

And this is the console output:

```
incoming message ...
[B@6142acb4
20
```

The bytearray in my server contains only 20 bytes, which looks like only metadata are transfered?

How can I transfer the recorded Blob to my Spring server and create a (webm) file of it? Do I have to change the parameter of my endpoint?

Comment: Where do you call `.readAsArrayBuffer()`?

Comment: @guest271314 in my stopRecording() method when I get the blob from the recorder. I added the snippet to my post

Comment: What is expected result of `System.out.println(input)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest you to create base64 string for your audio blob using below code:

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
 var base64data;
 reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 reader.onloadend = function() {
      base64data = reader.result;                
      console.log(base64data);
  }
```

You will get base64 string like this :

```
data:audio/webm;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAAyzN3N....
```

Now in your backend change your stream method code to this:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
public void stream(String base64Audio) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("incoming message ...");
        Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] decodedByte = decoder.decode(base64Audio.split(",")[1]);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("MyAudio.webm");
        fos.write(decodedByte);
        fos.close();
}
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot. I was planning to send the audio chunks as binary but I just realised that the base64 string is just slightly larger than the blob.

Comment: Hi Ajit Soman, how can you decode that same binary string and play back in the frontend?

Comment: @Fernando , You set base64 string to source tag . Example:
`<audio controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="data:audio/wav;base64,...." />
</audio>`